Why is it "wild" and not *wilt? English 'd' corresponds to German 't' even after 'l', as seen in "kalt"
So, as far as I can see, the general rule is that English 'd' corresponds to German 't' in native words ("day"-"Tag", "cold"-"kalt", "dream"-"Traum", "red"-"rot", "do"-"tun", "death"-"Tod", "dale"-"Tal", "ride"-"reiten", "blood"-"Blut", "dew"-"Tau", "deep"-"tief", "good"-"gut", "god"-"Gott", "drive"-"treiben", "drink"-"trinken", "drop"-"Tropfen", "dove"-"Taube", "deaf"-"taub", "daughter"-"Tochter", "bread"-"Brot"...) and early Latin loanwords ("desk"-"Tisch"...). So, why is it "wild" and not *wilt?

When you look up the etymology, it seems that it was spelled with a d already hundreds of years ago. Similarly, tag was spelled with a t hundreds of years ago. I suspect the answer is found rather on the English side, not the German one.

I don't know enough for a full answer, but wild is reconstructed as having a thorn (th sound) in Proto-Germanic: *wilþijaz, whereas e.g. good < *gōdaz, cold < *kaldaz. In contrast consider path and Pfad < *paþaz, and death and Tod < *dauþuz . From those examples it seems the question might be, why is the English word wild and not wilth

on the reddit thread linking to this https://www.reddit.com/r/etymology/comments/1hqimic/why_is_the_german_word_for_wild_spelt_wild_and/ it's pointed out that German wild also has synchronic reasons to be spelled that way: it's derived forms (e.g. wilder, am wildesten) have a voiced d
